# Sqoop cannot import data when using Ranger

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, apache-ranger

I'm using HDP-2.6, Ranger is enable to manager permission

I added a policy in Ranger to given full permission(read, write, execute) to yarn on /data, with 'recursive' enabled

I want to use Sqoop to import data from mysql to hive. but each time, I got the following exception:

```
30998 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading data to table ods.test_table
30998 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading data to table ods.test_table
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=EXECUTE, inode="/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00000.gz":admin:hadoop:drwx------
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=EXECUTE, inode="/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00000.gz":admin:hadoop:drwx------
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:353)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:353)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer$RangerAccessControlEnforcer.checkDefaultEnforcer(RangerHdfsAuthorizer.java:428)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer$RangerAccessControlEnforcer.checkDefaultEnforcer(RangerHdfsAuthorizer.java:428)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer$RangerAccessControlEnforcer.checkPermission(RangerHdfsAuthorizer.java:365)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer$RangerAccessControlEnforcer.checkPermission(RangerHdfsAuthorizer.java:365)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1950)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1950)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1934)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1934)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1903)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1903)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setPermission(FSDirAttrOp.java:63)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setPermission(FSDirAttrOp.java:63)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermission(FSNamesystem.java:1850)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermission(FSNamesystem.java:1850)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setPermission(NameNodeRpcServer.java:821)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setPermission(NameNodeRpcServer.java:821)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:465)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:465)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
31222 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347)
31223 [Thread-28] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2347)
```

at first I thought that Ranger permission didn't work, but in Range audit log, it shows this:

```
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.446","access":"WRITE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00002.gz","resType":"path","action":"write","result":1,"policy":10,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"ranger-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269954","seq_num":433117,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.446","access":"WRITE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00002.gz","resType":"path","action":"write","result":1,"policy":10,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"ranger-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269955","seq_num":433119,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.447","access":"READ","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","resType":"path","action":"read","result":1,"policy":10,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"ranger-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269956","seq_num":433121,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.447","access":"EXECUTE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00000.gz","resType":"path","action":"execute","result":0,"policy":-1,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"hadoop-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269957","seq_num":433123,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.448","access":"EXECUTE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00001.gz","resType":"path","action":"execute","result":0,"policy":-1,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"hadoop-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269958","seq_num":433125,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.448","access":"EXECUTE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00002.gz","resType":"path","action":"execute","result":0,"policy":-1,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"hadoop-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269959","seq_num":433127,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.449","access":"WRITE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00003.gz","resType":"path","action":"write","result":1,"policy":10,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"ranger-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269960","seq_num":433129,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.449","access":"WRITE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00003.gz","resType":"path","action":"write","result":1,"policy":10,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"ranger-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269961","seq_num":433131,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
{"repoType":1,"repo":"xstudy_hadoop","reqUser":"yarn","evtTime":"2018-03-05 17:33:18.451","access":"EXECUTE","resource":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/part-m-00003.gz","resType":"path","action":"execute","result":0,"policy":-1,"reason":"/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table","enforcer":"hadoop-acl","cliIP":"10.0.30.2","agentHost":"master","logType":"RangerAudit","id":"727c87c5-eeba-465e-ad8d-f1129c01801f-269962","seq_num":433133,"event_count":1,"event_dur_ms":0,"tags":[],"cluster_name":"xstudy"}
```

from the audit log, yarn just cannot have execute permission, why? I'm 100% sure that the permission is given.

I've two questions:

1. Why yarn cannot get 'execute' permission on folder /data?
2. Sqoop already imported data, why yarn asked 'execute' permission?

======add more info=====

Today, I tried to run sqoop command on a Linux machine in the cluster, it's exactly the same command, with same arguments, it's executed successfully, en.....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the owner of directory `/data/hive/warehouse/ods/test_table/` is user `admin` who is `hadoop` group member. And user `yarn` does not have permission to execute jobs there, because of `drwx------`.

Try to change permission to directory. Run command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod -R 775 /data
```

And try to rerun your job.

Comment: The permission is managed by Ranger, from the audit log, you can see that yarn has read/write permission